# Firebase query taking long time

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase for backend and react for frontend. Realtime is working fine but when I load page query takes 4 to 5 seconds to ge data from firestore. I want to know what is the issue. is it problem with firebase or with my code.

```
        const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
        console.log('ss', docSnap.data())
```

I see that apending data into component is not time consuiming. it is query which is taking time. Is it problem because I am using free version of firestore?

configuration

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "**********",
  authDomain: "portfolio-8e33f.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://portfolio-8e33f-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "****",
  storageBucket: "portfolio-8e33f.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "502330908580",
  appId: "**********",
  measurementId: "G-YD3HG54N45"
};
```

Region
asia-east1

I am in Pakistan

I am at local host at the moment.

This code is on client side

My internet connection is having 2MB/sec speed

I am on window.

What do you mean by server side rendering?

Comment: Please provide more details as there are many factors that can influence the time-to-load of a page. e.g. Where is your Firestore instance? Which country you are in? Is this code on the client or the server? What platform is making the request? How stable is your internet connection? Have you considered server-side rendering?

Comment: @samthecodingman

Comment: Refer to the [sample code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document). Attach a screen-shot of users collection.

Comment: Yeah... 400ms for 728 bytes.  :/

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60229124/15774176):

> The query performance is dependent on the size of the result. Since 10
> Mb is larger than 10Kb, it will be slower to get 10Mb than it is to
> get 10Kb. That applies both to the transfer over the network as to the
> reading of the data from disk or memory. Reading more data simply
> takes more time. The guarantee Firestore makes is that the amount of
> data in the collection has no effect on the query performance. So if
> you get 10Mb of data from 10Gb of data in the collection, it will take
> the same amount of time as when you get the same 10Mb from a 10Tb
> collection.

There are several reasons mentioned in the [blog](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-cloud-firestore-query-slow-e081fb8e55dd) that might be causing your query to run slow:

> **1:**   Probably the most common explanation for a seemingly slow query is that your query is, in fact, running very fast. But after the
> query is complete, we still need to transfer all of that data to your
> device, and that’s the part that’s running slowly.
>
> **2:**  offline cache is too big So while Cloud Firestore in the cloud indexes every field in every document in every collection, it doesn’t
> (currently) build any of those indexes for your offline cache. This
> means that when you query documents in your offline cache, Cloud
> Firestore needs to unpack every document stored locally for the
> collection being queried and compare it against your query.

For following the best practices, you can refer to the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices).
For getting to know more about server side rendering, you can refer to the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54067374/15774176):

**Admin SDK & Firebase Function Caching**

> Firebase functions that are handling GET requests support [server
> caching the response](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#manage_cache_behavior). This means that subsequent hits from
> identical queries will not re-run all of my functions (firebase reads,
> other function invocations) - it will just instantly respond with the
> same data again.
>
> **Process**
>
> **1.** Anonymous client visits a server-side rendered reactjs page.
>
> **2.** Initial load rendering on server triggers a firebase function (https
> trigger)
>
> **3.** Firebase function uses Admin SDK to read from secured
> firestore database
>
> **4.** Function caches the response for 3 hours `res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=600, s-maxage=10800');`
>
> **5.** Subsequent requests from any client anywhere for the next 3 hours
> are served from the cache - avoiding unnecessary reads or additional
> computation / resource usage
>
> **Note -** caching does not work on local - must deploy to firebase to test caching effect.